# Something wrong with NSCalender in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

i have been developing a weather app for iPhone and everything is working fine on iOS5 but there is something very strange about the days that are being displayed on iOS6....

but the strange this that this code returns `satuarday instead of monday sunday instead of tuesday` and so on.... but it is working fine on iOS 5

i am using the following method to display the days of the week..

```
-(NSString*)calculateDayOfTheWeek:(NSString *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    // [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:date];
   // NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit  fromDate:date1];

    int w = [comps weekday];
    //  NSLog(@"%i",w);

    if(w == 1)
        return @"Sun";
    else if (w == 2) 
        return @"Mon";
    else if(w == 3)
        return @"Tue";
    else if (w == 4) 
        return @"Wed";
    else if(w == 5)
        return @"Thu";
    else if (w == 6) 
        return @"Fri";
    else if (w == 7) 
        return @"Sat";

    else
        return @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ahhhhh..... i figured that out.... they have changed the date format from `YYYY-MM-dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd` ...

that might be a help to someone....